# Service for assisting an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, web-crawler

I am developing a MVC Web Application which isn't something special (basically displaying information from the DB). However I want to have an additional service running with the application which will be doing some scraping from a given url and populating the database. What are the different types of services which I can use and which one of them would suit me best for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a long running service running in a separate thread in a web app is a bad idea (if that's what you were thinking)

I would look at creating a windows service as this is far more robust.

Take a look at using something like [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) as this will reduce the pain of testing/debugging/deploying